# Excel 2010 OFFSET and INDIRECT functions inside range formulas

Tags: excel-2010, excel-indirect

Has anyone had experience of using the Excel `OFFSET` or `INDIRECT` spreadsheet functions inside a range formula?

I want to use a sum a column of values, but with a horizontal offset specific to each row, where the size of the offset is a different column. So e.g. if the data in range `A1:C3` is:

```
[1  2  3;
 1  2  3;
 1  2  3]
```

And the offset given in `D1:D3` is `[0; 1; 2]`, I want to use some syntax like `{=sum(offset(A1:A3, 0, D1:D3)}` to give 6.

Another option would be to use the INDIRECT function, using syntax like `{=SUM(INDIRECT("R"&ROW(A1:A3)&"C"&D1:D4,FALSE))}`.

Both of these return the result as it if was just the first element of the matrix and vector, i.e. 1. Is this a restriction on these functions, or there is a way around this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(the answer is completely reedited after the discussion in the comments)**

The OFFSET function is of no use here, as it operates with ranges and not with individual cells.

For the SUM function, everything is quite easy `{=SUM(A1:C3*(COLUMN(A1:C3)=D1:D3))}`. Or you might even avoid using the arrays with `=SUMPRODUCT(A1:C3,(COLUMN(A1:C3)=D1:D3))`. Note that column D now should refer to a specific column number and not to an offset from the first column, i.e. `1;2;3`.

For other functions, it's more difficult a) because they count zeros (false values) from the matrices; b) because they usually don't work with non-contiguous arrays (and any attempt to exclude zero-values from the matrix runs into the #value error). However, the combination of FREQUENCY and INDEX does the trick:

- finding average: `{=(SUM(A1:C3*(COLUMN(A1:C3)=D1:D3)))/INDEX(FREQUENCY((A1:C3*(COLUMN(A1:C3)=D1:D3)),0),2)}`
- finding median: `{=MEDIAN(LARGE((A1:C3*(COLUMN(A1:C3)=D1:D3)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&INDEX(FREQUENCY((A1:C3*(COLUMN(A1:C3)=D1:D3)),0),2)))))}`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I made myself clear.  The array D1:D3 is not (column, height, width) but an array of column offsets.  I.e., what I want to do is (A1 offset by 0 columns) + (B1 offset by 1 column) + (C1 offset by 2 columns).  So your suggestions are helpful but don't answer the problem I have unfortunately.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @TimX, sorry, I'd be glad to help but now it seems even more confusing than before. Column in the OFFSET function defines the starting point of calculations. So, if you want to sum up the range (A1:A3) with the offset (A1 offset by 0 columns) + (B1 offset by 1 column) + (C1 offset by 2 columns), then it'd be equivalent to summing up (A1:A3) + (C1:C3) + (E1:E3). Is that what you want?

Comment: No: I want A1 + B2 + C3.  Which is the column A1:A3 with the column offsets [0, 1, 2].  Hope that is clear,

Comment: @TimX OK, now everything is a lot easier! You don't even need the offset function or arrays, actually. Try this: `=SUMPRODUCT(A1:C3,--(COLUMN(A1:C3)=D1:D3))` or, essentially the same, `{=SUM(A1:C3*(COLUMN(A1:C3)=D1:D3))}`. If it works as you wish, I'll edit the answer to make it correct for your needs so that you could accept i.

Comment: Forgot to clarify that `D1:D3` in both formulas above should contain a reference to a specific column number rather than an offset from the A column, that is `1;2;3` instead of `0;1;2`.

Comment: @TimX Did you try the suggested formulas, did they work as you would have wanted? Or is there anything else I could do for you?

Comment: That is really great, thanks and a really nice way to solve this problem too.  Yes, does just what I want, appreciated!

Comment: One more question actually.  This works great for SUM since the elements in the matrix that I don't want are set to 0.  However I'd like to this form with other Excel functions too, specifically AVERAGE and MEDIAN, where I can't use this syntax as the zeros change the result.  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @TimX I've edited the answer, adding the formulas for finding average and median values, too.

Comment: Two further comments (having had time to play around with this): if there are no blank rows, we can't we replace the INDEX(FREQUENCY...)) syntax with ROWS()?  Also can you think of a neat way to handle non-numeric data, e.g. ignore #N/A or VALUE! inputs?  Thanks again.